# How to make tableview's scroll bar scroll in a smaller rect than table's frame?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

How to make tableview's scroll bar scroll in a smaller rect than table's frame?

Like this:A UITableViewController in a UINavigationController.

Tableview's frame is (0,0,320,480)(This frame said by NSLog), its scroll bar is always under 44px. So scroll bar will not displayed behind navigation bar.

How to archive this? Special thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please can u be a bit more clearer ?? u want to reduce the size of the scrollbar ??

Comment: YES, my table 's height is 480px, and i want its scroll bar stay under 44px, so scroll bar will not display behind navigation bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You coud set scroll edge insets. For example:

```
UIScrollView *scrollView;
[scrollView setScrollIndicatorInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(44, 0, 0, 0)];
```

As `UITableView` inherits `UIScrollView` all this methods are available.